# How to get up-to-date collection on subscription onReady (formerly onComplete)

Tags: meteor, publish-subscribe

I've run into a an issue with the `onReady` callback on [Meteor.subscribe](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_subscribe). When it is called, it is as the documentation states: The subscription has been marked as complete. However, the collection that it is modifying may not be done processing differences between the last subscription.

A quick demonstration can be seen by modifying the Todos example:

`$ meteor create --example todos`

Edit `client/todos.js`, see line 34. Replace the autosubscribe block with:

```
Meteor.autosubscribe(function () {
  var list_id = Session.get('list_id');
  var onReady = function (done) {
    var list, todos = Todos.find();
    if (todos) {
      list = todos.map(function (todo) {
        return todo.text;
      });
      if (done) {
        console.log("subscription onReady called again 100ms later:", list);
      } else {
        console.log("subscription onReady called:", list);
        setTimeout(function () {
          onReady(true);
        }, 100);
      }
    }
  };
  if (list_id)
    Meteor.subscribe('todos', list_id, onReady);
});
```

Launch the example, and click from one Todo List to the other (see top left) while watching the console. You'll notice that when `onReady` is called, the collection contains both the documents from the previous Todo List concatenated with the newly selected Todo List.

This isn't really a bug, because the `onReady` has never implied that it would be fired when the *collection* was up-to-date, but only when the *subscription* has completed.

Any suggestions to approach this? Is there a way to be notified immediately once the collection has been brought up-to-date after a subscription? I wonder if I should be relying on `.observe`... but on the client? Is that available client-side? I may try this tomorrow... but I'd love to hear solutions

FYI: My use case revolves around the [typeahead Bootstrap JS plugin](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead). I am firing a subscription with a search query to the server. The server publishes the search results, and as soon as the client receives this data (was hoping onReady would be the right choice...), I proceed to populate/update the typeahead source.

Comment: I've managed to get this working by indeed using a client-side observe. I'll post some code shortly to demonstrate how this would be done

Comment: After sleeping and regaining a clear head, it struck me that autosubscribe did exactly what I needed. It seems so obvious now...

Answer (score 0):

I asked a similar question here: [Is there any way to know when an meteor subscription is 'valid'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10794555/is-there-any-way-to-know-when-an-meteor-subscription-is-valid)

In short, you are correct about what's going on; the answer is just to filter the `Todos` collection appropriately when you use it:

```
Template.foo.todos = function() { 
  return Todos.find({list_id: Session.get('list_id')});
}
```